# Additivity for closed intervals

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\mathscr{F}$ be the set that contains all finite, disjoint union of closed or open intervals. Given $A\in \mathscr{F}$, let $\mu(A)=1$ if, for some positive $\varepsilon$, $A$ contains the interval $(0,\varepsilon)$. Otherwise let $\mu(A)=0$. Prove that $\mu$ is not countably additive.

By definition, I need to exhibit disjoint sets $A_1,A_2,\ldots\in\mathscr{F}$ such that $A=\cup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i\in\mathscr{F}$ and $\mu(A)\neq \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\mu(A_i)$. How is that possible?

It seems to me that if I pick some set $A_i$ to contain $[a,b]$ where $a\leq 0 < b$, then the sums on both sides is $1$, otherwise it's $0$.

Comment: @William I agree with you. Now that I read again, I think this exercise takes intervals to be either open or closed. I'll edit the problem. Let's see how that changes things?

Comment: In this case, we can probably take something like the union of $[\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n})$.

Comment: Yes, I get it. See my answer. I think your original post said that $F$ contains only closed intervals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the set $A_n$ to be $[\dfrac{1}{n+1},\dfrac1n)$. Then $A=[0,1)$, so $\mu(A)=1$ but $\mu(A_i)=0$ for all $i$.

Comment: These intervals are not closed.

Comment: I think your original post said that the intervals should be closed.

Answer (score 0):

Pick any $\epsilon > 0$. Let $A = [0, \epsilon/2]$. Now take the midpoint of the interval $[\epsilon/2, \epsilon]$, call it $p_1$, and let $B_1$ be the closed interval centered at this point, of length equal to the distance from the point to $\epsilon$. Next, take $p_2$ and $p_3$ to be the midpoints of the intervals that are left after removing from $[0, \epsilon/2]$ the intervals $A$ and $B_1$. Take $B_2$ and $B_3$ to be the intervals centered at $p_2$ and $p_3$, again of length equal to the distance from $p_i$ to the boundary. Continue this procedure. At the end, you will end up with a sequence of intervals $A, B_1, B_2, \dots$, all closed, all disjoint, and whose union is equal to the interval $[0, \epsilon]$, but none of which contains $(0, \epsilon)$. Thus you get $1 = \mu(A\cup B_1\cup\cdots) \neq \mu(A) + \mu(B_1) + \cdots = 0$.

Comment: Oh, didn't you say the statement was originally wrong (and I agree with you that it was wrong)? I think $\epsilon$ is allowed to vary, so you can't fix $\epsilon$ like that.

Comment: Yes, but then I thought of the above construction. I realize that $\epsilon$ is allowed to vary. In the above construction, none of the sets $B_i$, $i = 1, 2, \dots$ contains an interval of the form $(0, \delta)$ for any $\delta$.